# Python 2.7: Close a dialog without exiting the entire application

Tags: python, python-2.7, dialog

I'm running a script coded in python from a scripts menu in a desktop application. It's basically a giant macro that I wrote and added a GUI to. I'm pretty sure the GUI is a really old one that my desktop app uses called dialogKit from MIT.
[GitHub still has it here.](https://github.com/typesupply/dialogKit)
The problem is the word "stop" at the very end of the dialog code. 
I keep getting a "stop is undefined" message, which I understand, but I've tried everything to close the dialog and if I use `exit()`, `sys.exit()`, I don't get an error, but it also closes my entire desktop app.

I need to close the dialog and keep the software open. 
The limited dialog documentation for what I'm using can be found [here](http://www.e-font.de/flpydoc/view_html.html).
(you might have to click on the Dialog section. Their site uses frames.)

```
class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = Dialog(self)
        self.d.size = Point(300, 340)
        self.d.Center()
        self.d.title = "Halftone" #<----- Title of the dialogue
        self.d.AddControl(STATICCONTROL, Rect(aIDENT, aIDENT, aIDENT, aIDENT), "frame", STYLE_FRAME)

        # more controls and methods..

        def on_ok(self, code):
            return 1

        def on_cancel(self, code):
            print "blah"

        def Run(self):
            return self.d.Run() 

    d = MyDialog()
    if d.Run()!= 1:
        stop
```

I just need a way to change `stop` to something that 1) will prevent the script from running, and 2) close the dialog without quitting the entire application. This is the functionality of a typical "cancel" button, which is what I want.

Another option is the method called `on_cancel()`, which I also tried and could get the event itself to work, but still the entire application quits with any kind of `exit()`.

The docs show a method called `End()`, which claims to terminate the dialog object, but I've tried and failed to get that to work either.

Comment: After a quick look at the documentation, I think that End() is what you want. How did you use it, and what happened?

Comment: I tried replacing `stop` with `d.End()` Then I tried defining a function called `End()` and inside that I tried `exit()` and `sys.exit()`

Comment: Did d.End() throw an exception? I think it should have - your class here doesn't have a function called End. You would have to use d.d.End(), or you could try putting self.d.End() in your on_cancel function inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm posting an answer because I think I have a handle on your problem.

Try replacing stop with:

```
d.d.End()
```

If that works, you might want to try putting:

```
self.d.End()
```

inside of the on_cancel function in your class. That should close the dialogue without closing your program.